# How to set a minimum delay for BlockUI?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to set a minimum display of the BlockUI but having trouble.  No matter what value I put in setTimeout, the element is unblocked immediately.

Here I'm setting up the options for the jQuery ajaxForm plugin:

```
  var options = {
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function () {
                 setTimeout($('#MyElement').unblock(), 5000);
            }
        };
```

And here I'm showing the BlockUI on 'MyElement' when my submit button is clicked.

```
 $('.submit').click(function () {
            window.showBlockUI($('#MyElement'));
        });
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Matt Ball - not sure I understand.  If I do e.preventDefault() on submit, the blockUI stays there forever because I'm not getting a response back from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function in your `setTimeout()`, not passing a reference to a function so it executes immediately and passes the return result of that function to `setTimeout()`.  Thus it executes immediately.

Change it to this:

```
complete: function () {
    setTimeout(function() {$('#MyElement').unblock()}, 5000);
}
```

or in a little less compact form where you can see it better:

```
complete: function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#MyElement').unblock()
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I love stackoverflow, seriously.  Thanks. (This answer will be accepted in 9 minutes)